# Limit of $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty}\big((2-e^{t/\sqrt{2s}})e^{t/\sqrt{2s}}\big)^{-s}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with convergence in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87061/help-with-convergence-in-distribution)

Could any one tell me how to calculate this limit,
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(2-e^{t/\sqrt{2s}})e^{t/\sqrt{2s}}}\right)^{s}$$

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Is this question any different than one you asked about just a while ago and were pointed to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/87067/15941)?  If so, I think this question should be closed.

Comment: 32 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(s) = (2 - e^{t/\sqrt{2s}}) e^{t/\sqrt{2s}}$.  Then as $s \to \infty$, 
$e^{t/\sqrt{2s}} = 1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{2s}} + \frac{t^2}{4s} + O(s^{-3/2})$, so 
$f(s) = 1 - \frac{t^2}{2s} + O(s^{-3/2})$, and $\ln f(s) = - \frac{t^2}{2s} + O(s^{-3/2})$.  Therefore $\left(\frac{1}{f(s)}\right)^s = e^{-s \ln f(s)}
\to e^{t^2/2}$.